# spring boot: hikari configs camelcase vs configs with lowercase and -

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I see in my projects, hikaricp configurations are mentioned in camel case and lower case letters sepearated by -. Which one is the correct approach (or) both the approaches work?

Configs with -

```
spring:   
  datasource:
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 30000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      max-lifetime: 1800000
      maximum-pool-size: 25
      minimum-idle: 3
```

Configs with camel case

```
spring:   
  datasource:
    hikari:
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      idleTimeout: 600000
      maxLifetime: 1800000
      maximumPoolSize: 25
      minimumIdle: 3
```

I am using spring boot 2.0.3 release. Is mentioning the configs in either of the approach will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches work because of [Relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) feature.

Spring boot supports both of these styles along with uppercase and underscore ones.